# Problem with log4j xml configuration

Tags: java, log4j

i have little question, my log4j.xml configuration is listed below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
     <logger name="com.alsodeep">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>  
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

and when i call a log.info("some info")  inside the com.alsodeep package it printed out twice, for example

```
INFO  AspectExample - Call it before method
INFO  AspectExample - Call it before method
Hello
INFO  AspectExample - Call it after method
INFO  AspectExample - Call it after method
List content [[23, 243, 234, 23432]]
INFO  App - final
INFO  App - final
```

i'm confused with this, whats wrong with my log4j settings.

PS when i remove appender from root element, everything is ok and my log info appear only once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove:

```
<appender-ref ref="console" />
```

from particular loggers and leave only one in root logger:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
     <logger name="com.alsodeep">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>  
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Your configuration is valid, however when you try to log something on `com.alsodeep`, it first gets appender to the appender associated directly to this logger and then propagates up. `com` has no appender associated, but `root` (parent of all loggers) has. By coincidence it is the same console appender, so it gets appended twice.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer: (*assuming that your example was simplified from a more complex logger/appender scheme*)

You can set the `additivity` ([see the "Appenders and Layout" section](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)) attribute on each logger to `false`. This will prevent the log event from propagating up the logger hierarchy.